# CSS border under/below list item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list for my navbar.  I want to have a border below the active li item, not just on the bottom.

I've been able to add the border to the bottom using border-bottom, but again, it needs to be below the li element.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my custom css so far, in addition to default Bootstrap navbar list:

```
.nav .active{
    border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

See below:

[image]

Comment: Create a demo what you tried sofar?

Comment: Let's see what HTML you have for us to work with at a minimum. Some CSS would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an example ..... use border-bottom with background-clip padding box

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Altarnatively you can try box shadow. see this

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I used your alternate box-shadow.  One line of code is all this took.  I appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr50sqez/)**

CSS:

```
ul.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:4px 10px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;

}
li:hover, li.active {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#"> Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"> Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Menu 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: grate! but bud, i think you have to use background clip padding box for that

Answer (score 0):

I typically use an :after for small details like this, to get the border outside the menu items normal height.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li class="active">About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
</ul>
<div class="main"> 
    Next Box
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul{
    /* for looks */
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
li{
    background:black;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:5px 20px;
}
li.active{
    position:relative;
}
li.active:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    border-top:5px solid yellow;    
    width:100%;
}
.main{
    background-color:#dddddd;
    min-height:400px;
}
```

Most of the css is just for presentation but the key stuff is on the **li**, the **li.active**, and the **li.active:after**.

You can check out my demo at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joncampbell/g0cLsov1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample I always use. Hope this can help you ;)
This method is using the **last child** of the **"li"** element as the border.
The class **"selected"** on **"li"** element choose the position of the border to stay **at initial**.
When the mouse is on one of the menu bar button, the bar will follow it by an animation.
If you don't want an animation, please just delete **ALL transition CSS style** in "**.menu > li:last-child**" class.
If you want to know more about last child CSS style, please go to this link >> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

```css
.menu, .menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 25px;
}

.menu li {padding: 0px 5px;}

.menu > li {
text-align: center;
width: 80px;
font-size: 14px;
}

.menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.5s ease;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: #ffa500;
}

.menu > li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -90px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #ffa500;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
 }

 .menu .selected {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
 }

.selected a {
  color: #ffa500 !important;
}

.menu li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-375px) !important;
  -moz-transform:translateX(-375px) !important;
  -ms-transform:translateX(-375px) !important;
  -o-transform:translateX(-375px) !important;
  transform:translateX(-375px) !important;
}
.menu li:nth-child(1).selected ~ li:last-child {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-375px);
  -moz-transform:translateX(-375px);
  -ms-transform:translateX(-375px);
  -o-transform:translateX(-375px);
  transform:translateX(-375px);
}
.menu li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-280px) !important;
  -moz-transform:translateX(-280px) !important;
  -ms-transform:translateX(-280px) !important;
  -o-transform:translateX(-280px) !important;
  transform:translateX(-280px) !important;
}
.menu li:nth-child(2).selected ~ li:last-child {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-280px);
  -moz-transform:translateX(-280px);
  -ms-transform:translateX(-280px);
  -o-transform:translateX(-280px);
  transform:translateX(-280px);
}
.menu li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li:last-child {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-185px) !important;
  -moz-transform:translateX(-185px) !important;
  -ms-transform:translateX(-185px) !important;
  -o-transform:translateX(-185px) !important;
  transform:translateX(-185px) !important;
}
.menu li:nth-child(3).selected ~ li:last-child {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-185px);
  -moz-transform:translateX(-185px);
  -ms-transform:translateX(-185px);
  -o-transform:translateX(-185px);
  transform:translateX(-185px);
}
.menu li:nth-child(4):hover ~ li:last-child {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-90px) !important;
  -moz-transform:translateX(-90px) !important;
  -ms-transform:translateX(-90px) !important;
  -o-transform:translateX(-90px) !important;
  transform:translateX(-90px) !important;
}
.menu li:nth-child(4).selected ~ li:last-child {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-90px);
  -moz-transform:translateX(-90px);
  -ms-transform:translateX(-90px);
  -o-transform:translateX(-90px);
  transform:translateX(-90px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menubox">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="selected">
          <a href="#">
            First
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
   Second
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
   Third
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
   Forth
    </a>
  </li>
  <li></li>
   </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```